# Expresso FreeMember - reset password form email

Tags: freemember

I'm testing the reset password form for FreeMember and emails are not arriving. Here's the code ([same as here](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/forgot_password_tag.md#forgot-password-tag-example)).

```
{exp:freemember:forgot_password return="/account/forgot_sent" }

            <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label><br />
                {field:email}<br />
                {error:email}
            <p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </p>

      {/exp:freemember:forgot_password}
```

No errors appear. No emails arrive. I've tested EE's native emailer and the emails arrive, so that's not the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you running the latest version of FreeMember?

Comment: @mjr Yep. Latest EE and Freemember. Other Freemember tags work just fine.

Comment: Did you try running this through a service such as SendGrid as Adrian suggested to see if you can trace down the missing emails? Any luck?

Comment: I haven't yet. I'm waiting on the client to make some moves. I'll come back to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly being caught in some form of spam filter.

As a starting point, I suggest you sign up for a service such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) (free for up to 200 emails/day) rather than sending email directly from your server. This will help diagnose the issue as you can log into their web console and check the emails are actually being sent.

Comment: I don't even remember which client this is for. :)